# Persisted date in database not equal to retrieved date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a simple entity class that has a Date property. This property corresponds to a MySQL datetime column.

```
@Entity
public class Entity {

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date startDate;

}
```

This is what an integration test I wrote looks like:

```
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
Entity entity = new Entity();
entity.setStartDate(now);
entityService.save(entity); // save entity to database
entity = entityService.get(entity.getId()); // get entity back from database
Assert.assertEquals(entity.getStartDate(), now);
```

I would expect those two dates to be equal but they are not! Actually, I have :

```
now.getTime() = 1350160029831
entity.getStartDate().getTime() = 1350160029000
```

so there is a small gap between the two dates. I am really wondering where this gap could come from. It is not always the same and varies each time I start the testing process.
In my database, the date stored is 2012-10-13 22:15:38.0.

Do I really need to clear milliseconds somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

> A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional
>   seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. Although this
>   fractional part is recognized, it is discarded from values stored into
>   DATETIME or TIMESTAMP columns. For information about fractional
>   seconds support in MySQL, see Section 11.1.5.6, “Fractional Seconds in
>   Time Values”.

Note that you shouldn't use equals to compare dates anyway, because the various Date subclasses have buggy implementations, which cause problems such as `a.equals(b) && !b.equals(a)`:

```
java.util.Date d1 = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2012-01-01");
java.util.Date d2 = new java.util.Date(d1.getTime());
java.util.Date d3 = new java.sql.Timestamp(d1.getTime());

System.out.println(d1.equals(d2)); // true
System.out.println(d2.equals(d1)); // true
System.out.println(d1.equals(d3)); // true
System.out.println(d3.equals(d1)); // false
System.out.println(d2.equals(d3)); // true
System.out.println(d3.equals(d2)); // false
```

Comment: So I should ged rid of the milliseconds part with something like this :Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);