# Retrieved Date does not equal persisted Date in database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime, jpa

I'm pretty new to Java and Hibernate. When I persist a Date and it's retrieved from MySQL it does no longer equal the date "format" before it was persisted (the value seems to be the same though). Just curious - how do I get around this?

This is the mapped attribute:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.util.Date;

// ...

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date registeredTime;

public Organization(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.registeredTime = new Date();
}
// ...
```

And this is the test:

```
@Test
public void testSaveAndFind() {

    Organization organization = new Organization("Acme Inc");

    long newId = organizationRepository.saveOrganization(organization);

    Assert.assertFalse("Id should not be 0 after saved.", 0L == organization.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals("Entity id and save return id should match.", organization.getId(), newId);

    Organization foundOrganization = organizationRepository.find(newId);

    Assert.assertEquals(
            "Found organization id should be the same as saved organization id.",
            organization.getId(),
            foundOrganization.getId()
    );
    Assert.assertEquals(
            "Found organization name should be the same as saved organization name.",
            organization.getName(),
            foundOrganization.getName()
    );
    Assert.assertEquals(
            "Found organization registered time should be the same as saved organization registered time.",
            organization.getRegisteredTime(),
            foundOrganization.getRegisteredTime()
    );
}
```

When running the test I get this failure: `Found organization registered time should be the same as saved organization registered time. expected:<Sun Jul 10 15:11:17 CEST 2016> but was:<2016-07-10 15:11:17.0>`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876726/persisted-date-in-database-not-equal-to-retreived-date) seems to address the same issue but the answer doesn't really give a solution. I hope someone can help!

Comment: Use a java.sql.Timestamp in your object instead of a java.util.Date, and as the answer stated, the Database type used might not have the same precision as your java object type.  You'll have to check out the actual long value used underneath, but what you put in won't be the same unless you make them match exactly by only using the same precision in your java date/Timestamp objects, or by using an equality check that ignores the extra precision on one side.

Comment: Timestamp seems a lot easier to work with, thanks! Hibernate seems to loose precision though, but that's another story :)

Comment: Actually the [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class is supplanted by [`java.time.Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) in Java 8 and later with a driver that complies with JDBC 4.2 or later. Pass via `getObject` & `setObject` methods on a `PreparedStatement`.